# adding a new port to an existing deployment kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I deployed a new application that use port 80 using kubectl, and forgot to add the port 443 on the deployment, I exposed the port 80 for the application through the load balancer, But now I need to add port 443 to my deployment.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the deployment and make the changes or patch the deployment using kubectl patch command.

To edit the deployment use the below command

```
kubectl edit deployment <depoloyment-name> -oyaml
```

add the changes and save the file.

Comment: Thank you P Ekambaran for your quick feedback, I tried to add a new port definition like this "ports:
        - containerPort: 443
          name: WordPress_443
          protocol: TCP" on the yaml file but it throw an error message "error: deployments.extensions "wordpress" is invalid"

Comment: @Jaouad ALLALI, could you add the deployment definition to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

as you can see I added a new port definition 443 to the yaml file, but when saving it says

k8sadmin@k8s-master-34239724-0:~$ kubectl edit deployment wordpress -oyaml
error: deployments.extensions "wordpress" is invalid
A copy of your changes has been stored to "/tmp/kubectl-edit-dtzxq.yaml"
error: Edit cancelled, no valid changes were saved.

Here is the definition

creationTimestamp: 2019-11-18T12:27:57Z
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: wordpress
  name: wordpress
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "233695"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/wordpress
  uid: da5a75cf-09fe-11ea-bfe8-001dd8b70024
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: wordpress-mysql
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: password
              name: mysql-pass
        image: wordpress:4.8-apache
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: wordpress
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: wordpress
          protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 443
          name: wordpress443
          protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts: